# Where is the R command mac

Tags: java, r, macos

I know this has kind of been asked before but I just don't know how to locate the program so I can run the R script.
I have a java swing program and on it I have a button whose action should be to run an external R script. I keep getting a "No such file or directory error" and I'm sure its because I don't know what command I should be running. I have RStudio installed. My code:

```
JButton btnSelfassessR = new JButton("SelfAssess R");
        btnSelfassessR.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/usr/bin/Rscript","Rscript /Users/sebastianzeki/EndoHistol.R"});
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        });
```

but actually I think the `/usr/bin/Rscript` is wrong and I don't know how to correct this. What should I be looking to put in here. What is the likely location for a standard install of RStudio on a mac El Capitan

Comment: if you run `which Rscript` in Terminal, what is the output?

Comment: See the last post in [this discussion](https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=16469).